# Parsing XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am still working on a project and I am enjoying it greatly.

I wanted to see if I could implement a live updating feed using XML

at the moment I dont even know how to parse this particular type of XML as all the tutorials I have found are for parsing node values etc

but I was thinking something along the lines of this

```
<Object name="ObjectName" type="ObjectType" size="ObjectSize" image="ObjectImage" />
```

if you guys could help me understand how to access the inner elements of from that node that would be amazing, and if it is not too much to ask just a small explanation so I understand. I know how to parse XML that looks like this using XElement

```
<Object>
    <Name>ObjectName</Name>
    <Type>ObjectType</Type>
    <Size>ObjectSize</Size>
    <Image>ObjectImage</Image>
</Object>
```

I just cant seem to parse the example at the top, I dont mind if its Linq as long as it is in C#, maybe tell me why you would chose one over the other? Also have you got any idea on how to perhaps check if the file has changed, so I could implement a live update?

Thanks for your Help

John

Comment: whats the problem with the xml(de)serializer in .NET? see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813. are you binded to this xml schema? if yes, forget this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example at the top uses *attributes* instead of sub-*elements* but it's just as easy to work with:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);
string name = (string) element.Attribute("name");
string type = (string) element.Attribute("type");
string size = (string) element.Attribute("size");
string image = (string) element.Attribute("image");
```

I usually prefer to use the [explicit string conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339184.aspx) instead of the [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value.aspx) as if you perform the conversion on a `null` reference, you just end up with a `null` string reference instead of a `NullReferenceException`. Of course, if it's a programming *error* for an attribute to be missing, then an exception is more appropriate and the `Value` property is fine. (The same logic applies to converting `XElement` values as well, by the way.)

Comment: That's a useful distinction between using the cast and the `Value` property that I never considered.  Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a domain object that represents your document (usually the case), then the XmlSerializer is quite easy to use.

```
[XmlRoot("Object")
public class Item
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public string Size { get; set; }
   public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));
Item item = (Item)ser.Deserialize(someXmlStream);
```

I find using this approach easier than manual parsing when an entire document represents a domain object of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

Use can also use `XEelment.FirstAttribute` to get the first attribute on the element and then `XAttribute.NextAttribute` to loop through them all. This doesn't rely on you knowing that the attribute is present.

```
XAttribute attribute = element.FirstAttribute;
while (attribute != null)
{
    // Do stuff
    attribute = attribute.NextAttribute`
}
```

Comment: Why loop through them instead of requesting the ones you want?

Comment: @Jon - I suppose it depends on what you want to do. Your way is more explicit. Also just giving an alternative.